# Crashes with warning sound while rendering

Tags: crash

I've built a system, mainly for archicad and cinerender. Overclocked ryzen to 3.8, vigorously tested it with memtest, furmark, and aida64. 10+ hours each. It was stable, temperatures where ok: less than 75 for GPU, less than 70 for CPU.
But now i discovered what OS occasionally freezes after 1+ hour rendering with following sound looped in speakers:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxEdXA5UU5mrZHlqYk92MC...

Today it happened again, even though I returned to default setting in bios, without any overclock.

AMD Ryzen 7 1700
ASUS PRIME B350M-A
Corsair Value Select 16GB DDR4
Thermaltake Berlin 630 Watt
Toshiba DT01ACA Series 2TB
Kingston SSDNow UV400 240Gb
Windows 10
and old ASUS GeForce GTX 560 DirectCu

Drivers are updated, windows updates installed.
What could it be? I've never heard of BIOS warning through speakers, I've though what even if it was temperature warning, it will come from speaker on MB.

Comment: Your link doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**DRAM UNDERVOLT**

All your components are decent quality, except maybe your memory. Ryzen demands high quality DRAM.

First make sure you have the very latest BIOS update before attempting the following:

The B350M chipset is a bit aggressive with autovolting, esp. on mobos with minimal power phasing. This can cause problems with budget memory.

Try undervolting DRAM below whatever the autovolt level is.

My system was only stable at default BIOS settings. My DRAM autovolt was around 1.3V, so I undervolted to 1.2V.

This stabilised all XMP profiles and CPU overclocks up to 4.0GHz.